# Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have a DB which has a custom data type **`FollowEntityType`** as a column.

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = arrayOf("id", "type"), tableName = "follow_info")
data class FollowInfoEntity(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "type") var type: FollowEntityType,
)
```

Since it is a custom data type, I have defined a type converter.

```
class FollowDatabaseTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun toFollowEntity(entityType: String?): FollowEntityType? {
        return FollowEntityType.from(entityType ?: Constants.EMPTY_STRING)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toString(entityType: FollowEntityType?): String? {
        return entityType?.name
    }
}
```

This works fine and I am able to store/retrieve values in the DB. However, in one of the queries, the build fails.

This is the query.

```
@Query("select * from follow_info where type in (:entityTypeList)")
fun getFollowedEntitiesByType(entityTypeList: List<FollowEntityType>) : List<FollowInfoEntity>
```

The build fails with the following error.

```
Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
    java.util.List<? extends FollowEntityType> entityTypeList, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

The error is for **entityTypeList** field, and according to the error, this type should be one of the columns in the DB. I already have **FollowEntityType** as one of the column types. I don't understand why it is failing. Please help me out as I am not finding any solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Where did you include your FollowDatabaseTypeConverter as `TypeConverters`? On top of `@Entity` or `@Database`. If it's on @Entity, then it has no affect on your `@Dao` queries.

Comment: Read more on `@TypeConverters` in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverters)

Comment: @musooff : I included it on top of database.

Comment: Then, maybe it's because it is `List<FollowEntityType>`. Try adding a type converter for `List<FollowEntityType>` to `List<String>`. If that's the case, then it must be a bug and you can report it.

Answer (score 41):

This error occurred for me when I updated the kotlin library version without updating the room database version.

I was using Kotlin 1.5.10 and Room version 2.2.5 that caused the problem. Changing Room to 2.3.0 fixed the error.

Comment: I had a similar issue after updating Kotlin to 1.6.0—updating Room from 2.3.0 to 2.4.0-beta01 resolved it.

Comment: Updating to 2.4.0-beta01 works. Note that you also have to upgrade the  compileSdk version to 31

Comment: Thanks! I updated my project and thanks to you I could fix that error!

Answer (score 25):

I also see the same issue with **Kotlin 1.7.10 + Room 2.4.2**.
No problem with **Kotlin 1.6.21 + Room 2.4.2**.

**Kotlin 1.7.10 + Room 2.5.0-alpha02** is also okay, so I guess we have to wait for Room 2.5.0 formal release before using Kotlin 1.7.x

2022/8/4: After the AndroidX team released a new version of ROOM. **Kotlin 1.7.10 + Room 2.4.3** is okay now.

2022/10/7: If you are using **Kotlin 1.9.0** or greater version, compile with **Room 2.5.2**  won't work again. You have to use **Kotlin 1.9.0 + Room 2.6.0-rc01(or greater version)**. Changing to use KSP instead of KAPT is also recommended by Google. I am using **Kotlin 1.9.0 + KSP 1.9.0-1.0.13 + Room 2.5.2**

Comment: Have you tried Room 2.4.3?

Answer (score 8):

Remove the suspend from the method when you use room query annotation. Like

Old

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM userSession where isSync=0 ORDER BY createdOnInMills")
suspend fun getUnSyncSession(): List<SessionModel>
```

remove Suspend

New

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM userSession where isSync=0 ORDER BY createdOnInMills")
fun getUnSyncSession(): List<SessionModel>
```

Comment: This one did the job quickly

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when I tried executing this Query in Dao interface;

```
@Query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE customModel = :customModel")
fun deleteData(customModel: CustomModel)
```

Fix it by adding @TypeConverters(MyConverter::class) as below;

```
@TypeConverters(MyConverter::class)
@Query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE customModel = :customModel")
fun deleteData(customModel: CustomModel)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this. kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> continuation);

For `Kotlin 1.9.0` and `Room 2.5.2`, i removed `kapt` plugin and replaced it with [ksp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72978960/3736955) following [this doc](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp). `ksp` and Kotlin have compatible versioning.

Answer (score 1):

> Kindly update the Kotlin and Room DB version, It worked for me
> I changed to **Kotlin 1.6.21 + Room 2.4.2.** and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using room 2.4.2 with a android docs copy pasted documentation

It seems like this is a manifestation of room <-> kotlin version mismatch

I do get

```
error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> continuation);
```

When i use

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0
```

when i use

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21'
```

i don't get this error