# Android - error: Type converters must receive 1 parameter

Tags: android, android-room

I have searched alot but couldn't get a solution.

I initially got this error

```
error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
    androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteQuery query);
```

So after searching a bit, decided to add the @TypeConverter annotation and the @TypeConverters() annotation in the database class

This is the error I am getting now.
**error: Type converters must receive 1 parameter.
public final androidx.sqlite.db.SimpleSQLiteQuery getAllQuery(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()**

My DAO has this -

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tea WHERE name == :name")
    fun getTea(name: String): LiveData<Tea>
```

My TypeCoverter class has this method

```
 @TypeConverter
    fun getAllQuery(sortBy: TeaSortBy, showOnlyFavorites: Boolean): SimpleSQLiteQuery {
        val queryBuilder = SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder
                .builder(DataTeaNames.TABLE_NAME)
                .orderBy(getSortColumn(sortBy))
        if (showOnlyFavorites) {
            queryBuilder.selection(DataTeaNames.COL_FAVORITE, arrayOf("1"))
        }
        return SimpleSQLiteQuery(queryBuilder.create().sql)
    }
```

In the repositroy:

```
fun getSortedTeas(sort: String, fileByFavorite: Boolean = false): LiveData<PagedList<Tea>> {
        val sortBy = SortUtils.TeaSortBy.valueOf(sort)
        val factory = dao.getAll(SortUtils.getAllQuery(sortBy, fileByFavorite))
        return LivePagedListBuilder(factory, PAGE_SIZE)
                .build()
    }
```

Apologies in advance, I am new to this use of TypeConverters in Room Database. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a mismatch of Kotlin and Room versions that caused my initial error as referred from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68052960/8442557

Also, I missed adding a @RawQuery annotation.

This solved my error.

Answer (score 2):

A class with a method to help `Room` understand the `Tea` class annotated with `@TypeConverter` is required.

For example: (using `Gson`)

```
class TeaConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun toTeaList(json: String): List<Tea> {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<Tea>>(){}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(json, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toJson(teaList: List<Tea>): String {
        val type = object: TypeToken<List<Tea>>(){}.type
        return Gson().toJson(torrent, type)
    }
}
```

Then add this converter to you database like:

```kotlin
@TypeConverters(TeaConverter::class)
abstract class TeaDatabase : RoomDatabase() {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Turns out it was a mismatch of Kotlin and Room versions that caused my initial error and the missing @RawQuery annotation. Had nothing to do with TypeConverters.